# How to print a range of pages that use sections with page numbers, in Microsoft Word on MacOS

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, printing

I have a word document that uses the Section and Page numbering option, so for example in Section 1 the first page is 1-1 the second page is 1-2, etc. I'm trying to print pages 2-3 and 2-4 however the print window identifies this as pages 2-3 and 2-4, or in other words pages: 2,3 and 2,3,4. On the Windows operating system you could do this, but I can't find a way to do this on the Mac and searching the internet didn't yield any results.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are confusing the displayed "page number" with the page number that the print dialog wants.  Yes "2-3" is going to be seen as pages 2&3 when printing. You need to specify the pages by their position instead.  According to https://www.webucator.com/blog/2010/08/printing-page-ranges-in-microsoft-word-2010/ you should use the format p#s#-p#s# (page#section#).  Whatever is displayed on the page using your preferred numbering format is actually not relevant.

Comment: I thought that too, but the print window doesn't recognize any page numbers higher than the pages without sections on them. In my document I have about 6 initial pages that are numbered 1,2,3,4,5,6 and then it starts with 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, etc. So it will recognize pages 1 through 6, but it doesn't recognize page 7 or higher.

Comment: Did you try using the select-and-scroll method described in the link, and see how it shows the page range?  e.g. select from p.1-7 thru 2-2 to print, and see how it is displayed in the print dialog.

Comment: I did. I tried printing page 10-11 (which is 1-7 and 1-8) but it returned a blank page. I tried p7s1-p8s1 and got a blank page as well.

Comment: I'd suggest posting a screenshot or two of the print dialog, e.g. what it shows if you select-and-print, and what you are putting in using the #p#s format. Also are you sure you put in #p#s and not #s#p?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to print 3rd page of section 2 use ctrl+p which will give a prompt asking you which pages to print

Comment: Unfortunately the print window doesn't recognize the 2-3 format, it thinks I'm trying to print pages 2 and 3, instead of page 2-3.

Comment: Is there any way to send the document? Or convert it to pdf ? That way the page numbers will be fixed

Comment: yes, that's what I do now is I save it to a pdf and then pull out the pages I want. I'm looking avoid that extra step though

Comment: https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-different-page-numbers-or-number-formats-to-different-sections-bb4da2bd-1597-4b0c-9e91-620615ed8c05&hl=en-IN.   Try this and lemme know if it worked

Comment: That's funny, I literally do exactly those steps for my word documents, have been for years because I have document control requirements where the pages revision status is in each footer.